# Loadbalancer for the GCP Private Service Connect Endpoints

Tags: gcp, loadbalancing

I have two Private Service Connect Endpoints to connect to a published service in two different regions. I am trying to find if it is possible to have a load balancer on my end to load balance between these two endpoints so that if one region is not available I could failover to another region.

[image]